# OAuth signature issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth, intuit-partner-platform, rauth

I'm trying to use python with the rauth library to connect to the QBO api on the intuit partner platform, and I've mostly gotten it to work correctly. However, I'm frequently getting errors when sending requests:

```
Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401
```

This message is also located in the response header when it fails:

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid"
```

The error code indicates that the request isn't being signed properly, but I'm using a standard oauth library to automatically sign the data, and it works about half of the time. my connection code is as follows:

```
if method is 'post':
    headers = {}
        if action in ['create', 'update', 'delete']:
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
        r = self.session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, params=params, header_auth=True)
else:
    r = self.session.get(url, params=params, header_auth=True)
```

Where self.session is an rauth.OAuth1Session.

An example generated request is:

```
GET /resource/customer/v2/682571780/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_nonce="d577f23920c96f8ee79eff6588c83c9ebf65cf20",oauth_timestamp="1366147949",oauth_consumer_key="qyprdCFOHBypPTK8XX0g8N4bZ8ceVA",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="qyprdp9p7diRBIt11In225OOGRzcgl9o4DsQRJduHJFP09gY",oauth_signature="w5V3u2ATnj/rDc9vFD7inr8MO6I%3D"
User-Agent: python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.5.0-17-generic
```

Is this an issue with the rauth library? Am I leaving out a parameter that would make it more stable?

Comment: "...but I'm using a standard oauth library to automatically sign the data" Are you not signing with rauth? Please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: No, when I mentioned 'library', I meant using rauth instead of custom signing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that the complete solution to my problem required two changes:

1. The `params` object I was passing was being preserved between requests in some cases, but apparently gets destructively modified when setting up the request. This meant that the oauth parameters were included in the next request, which interfered somehow with rauth setting it up.

   The only differences that I noticed were that the parameters were in a different order, but it's possible that the oauth parameters were being treated as part of the signed content and then being overwritten after the signature was generated, invalidating it. Whatever the cause, this change fixed 90% of the failures I was getting.
2. Resetting `header_auth` back to `False` as suggested by maxcountryman. Even though the [spec for qbo requests](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0005_Request_Header) says to put the authentication in the header, apparently that doesn't always work. The error rate I was getting with this setting was only around 10%, but without it I'm no longer getting any signature errors.

Comment: They probably haven't implemented header auth properly, it sounds like. Your params issue could be related to using a mutable type. Without more specific code examples and proper tracebacks it's hard to say anything further.

Comment: Yes, I was passing in a mutable dictionary and reusing the same one across multiple requests, which caused the issue. It might be nice if the params dict passed in wasn't destructively modified like that, but the fix was easy enough once I figured out it was a problem.

Comment: It's not destructively modified, I think you're confused: it's treated the same way as Requests treats `params` and `data`; these respective dicts are updated in a non-destructive way, excepting optional OAuth parameters of course.

Comment: I say destructively modified because the same dict was updated as a side effect. In my mind, a non-destructive operation creates a new object with the updates instead of changing the old one.

However, there's not much point in arguing about the terminology. Passing in a fresh dict each time fixes the problem, and it looks like you added a fix that does that automatically just a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Rauth author here:

"The error code indicates that the request isn't being signed properly..."

Actually, this isn't necessarily true: it really indicates that the provider was unable to verify the request and is indicating the signature is incorrect. But this can also mean the signature is simply missing (incidentally that would technically be incorrect). I would try setting `header_auth` to `False`. This is a common issue where the provider is not prepared to process header based authentication and then confusingly returns an signature_invalid error.

Additionally you mention you're using a library to automatically sign the request, is that a library in addition to rauth? If so, I would strongly recommend against doing that: rauth is self-contained and does the signing for you. You should avoid combining it with other OAuth libraries.

Finally if you continue to have problems, feel free to reach out to me directly or open an issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/litl/rauth).

Comment: The library mentioned was rauth; the request is created exactly as in the post. Also, according to the [spec](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0005_Request_Header), they prefer the oauth info to be in the header. However, removing header_auth did improve stability.